# Dropout Layer with zero dropping rate

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, dropout

I'm having trouble understanding a certain aspect of dropout layers in PyTorch.

As stated in the [Pytorch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html) the method's signature is `torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)` where `p` is the dropout rate.

What does this layer do when choosing `p=0`? Does it change its input in any way?

Comment: `p=0` would be equivalent to no dropout; what is you confusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dropout](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/dropout.html#Dropout) with `p=0` is equivalent to the identity operation.

In fact, this is the exact behaviour of Dropout modules when set in `eval` mode:

> During evaluation the module simply computes an identity function.

Comment: Thanks! This true regardless of being in `train` or `eval` mode right?

Comment: @Shir `eval` mode disables dropout layers completely by setting `p=0`, so in this case their behaviour is identical: ["During evaluation the module simply computes an identity function."](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/dropout.html#Dropout)